# Abnormal behavior of cross thread operation

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a cross thread operation with following structure.

The anomaly is that when I put breakpoint on record query operation, the record is not null. However, when I remove the breakpoint and let the program executes, the record is always null. I have made sure that the record retrieval process is correct. Is this some kind of cross thread operation anomaly?

Here is the invoke procedure

```
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        var filters = new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
          {
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("from_userid", ParentMessage.from_userid),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("to_userid", this.SourceUser.id),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("group_header_id", ParentMessage.group_header_id),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("message", ParentMessage.message),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("is_read", 0)
          };

            MessagerLogModel MessageLog = null;

            MessageLog = MessagerLogs.CustomFilter(filters).FirstOrDefault();


            if (MessageLog == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("message log model not found in database.");
                return;
            }
}));
```

And, here is the operation to retrieve database records.

```
public static List<MessagerLogModel> CustomFilter(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] _params)
{
    var result = new List<MessagerLogModel>();

    string Query = @"SELECT * FROM messager_logs";

    List<MySqlParameter> commandParams = new List<MySqlParameter>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> param in _params)
    {
        if (commandParams.Count == 0)
            Query += " WHERE ";
        else
            Query += " AND ";

        if (param.Value == DBNull.Value)
            Query += param.Key + " IS @" + param.Key;

        else
            Query += param.Key + " = @" + param.Key;


        commandParams.Add(new MySqlParameter("@" + param.Key, param.Value));
    }

    MySqlDataReader r =
        MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Shared.getConnectionString(),
        Query, commandParams.ToArray());

    while (r.Read())
        result.Add(dataToModel(r));

    r.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's called a race condition.  You need to make sure that the value can't change in the background.  For example, make a copy.

Comment: I assumed that all these operations inside `Action` method are on a single thread. Should the code next to data query procedure wait for it to finish execution?

Comment: That depends what `Invoke()` does.

Comment: I have updated my question to include more codes. Please have a look.

Comment: where is the "cross thread operation" and "multithreading" you're talking about? is it only the `Invoke`?

Comment: The whole Invoke statement is running on another thread, not the ui thread.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the "lambda" in your Action. You include some values there: they are not copied into the lambda expression at the time when the lambda gets defined, but at the moment the lambda is executed. Member variables like ParentMessage.from_userid might have changed meanwhile.